# How do I use Cocoa to get a URL of a bundle with a given ID, or vice versa?

Tags: cocoa, url, foundation, bundle-identifier, app-bundle

If I have a bundle identifier as a `String`, how do I find out the `URL` of the bundle that it identifies? Conversely, if I have the `URL` of a bundle, how do I find out that bundle's identifier as a `String`?

I would like to only use Foundation/Cocoa APIs to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Bundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle)'s [`init(identifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411929-init) followed by [`bundleURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1415654-bundleurl) to get a URL from a bundle identifier, and [`Bundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle)'s [`init(url:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1409352-init) followed by [`bundleIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1418023-bundleidentifier) to get a bundle's URL.

#### Example:

```swift
let myBundleUrl = Bundle(identifier: "com.me.app")?.bundleURL

let theirBundleId = Bundle(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/Mail.app"))?.bundleIdentifier
```

---

Just as a note, [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) also has an API for getting a URL from a given bundle ID: [`urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534053-urlforapplication). I didn't recommend this one here because `NSWorkspace` doesn't have an API for getting an identifier from a `URL`.

Comment: For me, only NSWorkspace approach works to find (another) app by its bundle ID.

Comment: @gavv Fascinating! So when you pass a bundle ID to `Bundle(identifier:)`, you get `nil`? Maybe a sandboxing thing 

Comment: Yep, IIRC I received nil.